# TypeError: Cannot read property 'summary' of undefined React Js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm having issues with my reactjs code im trying to pass some props through from an array to a class but its giving me a undefined error.

FAQ.js

```
import React from "react";
import Accordions from '../components/Parts/Accordions';
import ApplyingWithUs from '../components/Parts/ApplyingWithUs';
...
export default class FAQ extends React.Component {
   render() {
        ...
return (
    <div>
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h4>The Basics</h4>
            <Accordions TheBasics={TheBasics}/>
            <h4>Appling With Us</h4>
            <ApplyingWithUs ApplyingWithUsDetails={ApplyingWithUsDetails}/>
        </div>
    </div>
   );
 }
}
```

I have removed the arrays as they are long and not causing the issue

Accordions.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from './Accordion';

export default class Accordions extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
                {this.props.TheBasics.map((basics)=> {
                    return <Accordion basics={basics} key={basics.id} />
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Accordion.js it is saying the error is at {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} {this.props.awu.summary} even though im passing everything through the same as {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} {this.props.basics.summary} just different names cause of different arrays where it is pulling data from

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
    active: {
        display: 'inherit',
    },
    inactive: {
        display: 'none',
    }
};

export default class Accordion extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            active: false
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle(){
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        });
    }

    render(){

        const stateStyle = this.state.active ? styles.active : 
        styles.inactive;

        const hand = {
            cursor:"pointer",
        }

        return (
            <li>
                <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                    {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} 
                    {this.props.basics.summary}
                </p>
                <p style={stateStyle}>
                    {this.props.basics.details}
                </p>
                <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                     {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} 
                     {this.props.awu.summary}
                </p>
                <p style={stateStyle}>
                     {this.props.awu.details}
                </p>
            </li>
         )
     }
 }
```

ApplyingWithUs.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from './Accordion';

export default class ApplyingWithUs extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
                {this.props.ApplyingWithUsDetails.map((awu)=> {
                    return <Accordion awu={awu} key={awu.id} />
                })}
            </ul>
         );
     }
 }
```

Please Help Me.

Comment: @TeaTime its breaking at the {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} {this.props.awu.summary} not the basics one that works on the accordion.js file

Comment: Where is the error stack trace?

Comment: In `Accordion` You have prop `awu` but where you send prop `basics` ?

Comment: @Andrew I add in basics in Accordions.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is, you are calling that component from 2 places (from `Accordions.js` and `ApplyingWithUs.js`). From one place you are passing `basics` and from other `awu`. So when you are calling from first place `awu` will be `undefined` and you are accessing the value `details` of `undefined`, that't why throwing the error. Same for second place also when accessing the value `summary` of `basics` (will be `undefined`).

Solutions:

**1.** Either pass all the values in `props` from both place.

**2.** Or put the conditions before using the value `baiscs.summary` like `basics && basics.summary`.

Check this:

```
render(){
    const stateStyle = this.state.active ? styles.active : 
    styles.inactive;

    const hand = {
        cursor:"pointer",
    }

    let {basics, awu} = this.props;

    return (
        <li>
            {basics ?
                <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                    {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} 
                    {basics.summary}
                </p>
            :null}

            <p style={stateStyle}>
                {basics && basics.details}
            </p>

            {awu ?
                <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                    {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} 
                    {awu.summary}
                </p>
            :null}

            <p style={stateStyle}>
                {awu && awu.details}
            </p>
        </li>
    )
}
```

Comment: This sort of works it passes them through but i now get one ► with the info next to it and one that comes out blank ►

Comment: because that value is blank, what you want, some default text if `basics.summary` is `undefined`?

Comment: its not blank its putting the data in but then duplicating the ►

Comment: what is expected behaviour?  it should render only one arrow with text, not the other one?

Comment: Yeah it should render one ► with the summary text next to it, then when you click it it shows the details in a normal <p> tag underneath and change the ► to ▼

Comment: almost like a spoiler box in bb code if you know what i mean. you click the area and it shows the hidden stuff underneath

Answer (score 1):

If `Accordion` not connected to `Redux` and recieve props only from parent, You forget to send prop `basics`. See comments in code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from './Accordion';

export default class ApplyingWithUs extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
                {this.props.ApplyingWithUsDetails.map((awu)=> {
                    return <Accordion awu={awu} key={awu.id} /* here must be basics={something} *//>
                })}
            </ul>
         );
     }
 }

export default class Accordion extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            active: false
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle(){
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        });
    }

    render(){

        const stateStyle = this.state.active ? styles.active : 
        styles.inactive;

        const hand = {
            cursor:"pointer",
        }

        return (
            <li>
                <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                    {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} 
                    {this.props.basics.summary} // or you can't use this prop
                </p>
                <p style={stateStyle}>
                    {this.props.basics.details}
                </p>
                <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                     {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} 
                     {this.props.awu.summary}
                </p>
                <p style={stateStyle}>
                     {this.props.awu.details}
                </p>
            </li>
         )
     }
 }
```